# Indexed Gradient operator on trigonometric functions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, notation, differentiation

$$\nabla_{i}\nabla_{j}\Big(\frac{\sin(kR)}{R}\Big)$$ Where $R$ is the distance between particle $i,j$. And $k$ is a constant

I took $\nabla_{i}=\frac{\partial}{\partial R_{i}}$ and $\nabla_{j}=\frac{\partial}{\partial R_{j}}$ and $R=R_{i}-R_{j}$.

After performing the calculation I obtained,
$$(\hat{R_{i}}\hat{R_{j}}-\delta_{ij})\Big(-k^2\frac{\sin(kR)}{R}-2k\frac{\cos(kR)}{R^2}+2\frac{\sin(kR)}{R^3}\Big)$$

However the same calculation was done in the book Molecular Quantum Electrodynamics by Craig. There the answer is different

$$-(3\hat{R_{i}}\hat{R_{j}}-\delta_{ij})\Big(\frac{k\cos(kR)}{R^2}-\frac{\sin(kR)}{R^3}\Big)-\hat{R_{i}}\hat{R_{j}}k^2\frac{\sin(kR)}{R}$$

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the right function to consider for $R$ is $R=\Vert\mathbf x_i-\mathbf x_j\Vert$ and the usual differentiation operators for the $\nabla$s.

So, if $\mathbf x_i = (x_i,y_i,z_i)$, then
$$R = \sqrt{(x_i-x_j)^2+(y_i-y_j)^2+(z_i-z_j)^2}$$
and
$$\nabla_i = \left(\frac\partial{\partial x_i},\frac\partial{\partial y_i},\frac\partial{\partial z_i}\right)$$
(similarly for $j$).

Comment: @MaxQuantum The answer just uses a different notation for the position vectors. Still, it's in bold notation so clearly $\bf x_i$ is just what you called the vector $R_i$. Basically, you forgot that $R$ is a distance (a norm of a vector between the particles). A unit vector is then just ${\bf R}/R$. Be careful, you are not consistent with your notation what is a vector in what isn't.

Comment: Actually I tried this taking R=square root of(R_{i}^2+R_{2}^2-2R_{i}R_{j}). I am getting an answer with R^{3/2}. Appreciate small help on this

Comment: @MaxQuantum please see the edits.